# Only wants to close menu by background div & button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs:

**First div:** its the background div ".menu_bg" (width + height 100%)

**Second div:** its the content (maybe width + height 40%)

So, if I click the "first div / background div" I want that the "first & second div" fades out. My Problem is, that this also happened when I only click the "second div / the content div".

Thats my code:

```
(function(window) {
    'use strict';

    var body = document.body,
        mask = document.createElement("div"),
        toggleSlideTop = document.querySelector(".toggle-slide-top"),
        slideMenuTop = document.querySelector(".slide-menu-top"),
        activeNav;
    mask.className = "mask";

    /* slide menu top */
    toggleSlideTop.addEventListener("click", function() {
        classie.add(body, "smt-open");
        document.body.appendChild(mask);
        activeNav = "smt-open";
    });

    /* hide active menu */
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".close-menu, .menu_bg")).forEach(function(el, i) {
        el.addEventListener("click", function() {
            classie.remove(body, activeNav);
            activeNav = "";
            document.body.removeChild(mask);
        });
    });
})(window);
```

Whats wrong?

---

**UPDATE:**

I create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ngoqepp/).

Comment: Please show us your HTML, or we cant help you^^

Comment: Ok, I have created a fiddle for you guys .... hope it helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your second `div` is nested to the first one. In this case any event fired on the second `div` will propagate up to all parent elements, until you call `event.stopPropagation()` method. So what you need is to call this method from `click` listener added to *nested* element. Somthing like:

```
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Yes, thats absolutly the problem, but your code doesn´t work for me ;(.

Comment: I think I understood what did you want. I updated my post. Try to add this code to your program.